# Initializing "complex" nested javascript/objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I am making a program that generates a Javascript file. I have never worked with Javascript, so I may be asking a stupid question :) Anyhow, this Javascript files gets initialized with data.

Here is an example line where I initialize an entry in an array with an object that contains two properties whereof one of them is an array containing 3 objects...

Or, well, that was the idea at least... Is there anyway I can do so so "M" becomes a real array that can be indexed normally?

```
W1[242] = {"W":"authors","M":{ "ArrItem0":{"U":32,"S":4.37},"ArrItem1":{"U":38,"S":4.02},"ArrItem2":{"U":406,"S":1.53} } };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
W1[242] = {"W":"authors","M":[ {"U":32,"S":4.37},{"U":38,"S":4.02},{"U":406,"S":1.53} ] };
```

Answer (score 3):

The array notation is the following, with brackets `[]`:

```
W1[242] = 
    { 
       "W": "authors",
       "M": [{"U":32,"S":4.37}, {"U":38,"S":4.02},{"U":406,"S":1.53}]
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to work with what is in M.  Here is one option where each element of M is it's own object.

```
W1[242] = {"W":"authors","M":[ {"U":32,"S":4.37},{"U":38,"S":4.02},{"U":406,"S":1.53} ] };
```

Comment: He wants non-associative array for M.